# Using an update statement for Access database (VB 2008)

Tags: vb.net, sql-update, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to create an update statement for my program that will update a database using SQL based on the data the user inputs, unfortunately I have the problem that I can only update one column at a time and sometimes none of them work. I am aware that this function is very basic and not very secure against attacks, but it is a small project that I am making. Unfortunately I only have basic programming skills so I am having trouble getting this part to work. If any help could be given it will be much appreciated.

```
Private Sub btnsave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnsave.Click

    Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection

    Dim d1 As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim d2 As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim d3 As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim d4 As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim d5 As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim d6 As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim d7 As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim d8 As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim d9 As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim d10 As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter

    Dim dt As New DataTable("Animals")

    'uses the 2010 compatible connection string
    con.ConnectionString = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = h:\Animals.accdb"
    con.Open()

    MsgBox("UPDATE Animals SET LatinName = '" & latintxt.Text & "'" & " WHERE AnimalName = " & "'" & Form1.txtname.Text & "'")
    d1 = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("UPDATE Animals SET LatinName = '" & latintxt.Text & "'" & " WHERE AnimalName = " & "'" & Form1.txtname.Text & "'", con)
    d2 = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("UPDATE Animals SET LocationFound = '" & locationtxt.Text & "'" & " WHERE AnimalName = " & "'" & Form1.txtname.Text & "'", con)
    d3 = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("UPDATE Animals SET AverageHeight = '" & heighttxt.Text & "'" & " WHERE AnimalName = " & "'" & Form1.txtname.Text & "'", con)
    d4 = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("UPDATE Animals SET AverageWeight = '" & weighttxt.Text & "'" & " WHERE AnimalName = " & "'" & Form1.txtname.Text & "'", con)
    d5 = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("UPDATE Animals SET DietaryNeeds = '" & diettxt.Text & "'" & " WHERE AnimalName = " & "'" & Form1.txtname.Text & "'", con)
    d6 = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("UPDATE Animals SET ConservationStatus = '" & statustxt.Text & "'" & " WHERE AnimalName = " & "'" & Form1.txtname.Text & "'", con)
    d7 = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("UPDATE Animals SET AverageLifeSpan = '" & lifetxt.Text & "'" & " WHERE AnimalName = " & "'" & Form1.txtname.Text & "'", con)
    d8 = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("UPDATE Animals SET BreedingSeason = '" & breedtxt.Text & "'" & " WHERE AnimalName = " & "'" & Form1.txtname.Text & "'", con)
    d9 = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("UPDATE Animals SET AverageLength = '" & lengthtxt.Text & "'" & " WHERE AnimalName = " & "'" & Form1.txtname.Text & "'", con)
    d10 = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("UPDATE Animals SET AnimalName = '" & nametxt.Text & "'" & " WHERE AnimalName = " & "'" & Form1.txtname.Text & "'", con)

    d1.Fill(dt)
    d2.Fill(dt)
    d3.Fill(dt)
    d4.Fill(dt)
    d5.Fill(dt)
    d6.Fill(dt)
    d7.Fill(dt)
    d8.Fill(dt)
    d9.Fill(dt)
    d10.Fill(dt)

    con.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: What leads you to believe that you "can only update one at a time"? From the looks of your code it seems that you are under the impression that you can only update one *column* (field) at a time. (Hint: That is simply not true.)

Comment: Sorry, that what I meant, I can only update one column at at time e.g. I can't simply input data into multiple fields and have them all update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To execute an update command you could write a single statement and use a [OleDbCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.aspx) with [ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executenonquery.aspx) method.

```
Dim cmdText As String = "UPDATE Animals SET LatinName=?,LocationFound=?,AverageHeight=?," + 
                 "AverageWeight = ?, DietaryNeeds = ?, ConservationStatus = ?, " + 
                 "AverageLifeSpan = ?, BreedingSeason = ?, AverageLength = ? " +
                 "WHERE AnimalName = ?"

Using con = new OleDbConnection("PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = h:\Animals.accdb")
Using cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdText, con)
    con.Open()
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1",latintxt.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2",locationtxt.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3",heighttxt.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4",weighttxt.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5",diettxt.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6",statustxt.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p7",lifetxt.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p8",breedtxt.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p9",lengthtxt.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p10",nametxt.Text)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
End Using
```

There are a couple of problems to be aware and that could lead  to an update failure.
First, all the parameters values are of type string and this could be your main problem. If the database fields are not of text type then you need to convert these values to the appropriate type.
For example, if the field `AverageHeight` is numeric (double) then the parameter should be written as:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3",Convert.ToDouble(heighttxt.Text))
```

and, of course, the text present in the heighttxt should be convertible to a double.

The second problem is the content of the parameter used to find the record to update.
In your query this field is named `AnimalName` and you search the record using `Form1.txtname.Text`, but in the same query text you try to update the same field used in the WHERE clause using `nametxt.Text`. Logically these two fields contains the same value so you need only one parameter.

Last point to remember, in OleDb the parameters are not recognized by their name but by their position inside the command text. So beware of the correct order in which the parameters are added to the parameter collection

Comment: Thank you for your response, however as I said my programming skills are very basic so I hope you don't mind that I have a few questions. How exactly would I use the code you have given, would I integrate it into my own or would I simply replace mine? and How exactly does cmdText work and what does it do?

Comment: @user2092379 Another consideration: `UPDATE` will only update *existing* records in the database, it will not add new records. To add new records you need to use an `INSERT` command, which has a somewhat different syntax than the `UPDATE` command.

Comment: @user2092379, the cmdText is your query without string concatenation of the values to update and to search for, this is better because the placeholders (?) will be replaced by the value in the corrispondent parameters collection. This replacemente is done by the framework that has a better knowledge how to pass these values (for example a single quote present in your textbox could wreak havoc with the string concatenation)

Comment: @user2092379, the code provided should replace all of your code.

Comment: @Steve Than you for that explanation. I have tried using the code you have given in my program but I have a few problems. The using statements require additional brackets but I cannot seem to place the in a place where it fixes the problem. The oleDbconnection is not declared and I am not to sure on what to declare them as.

Comment: @user2092379 recheck the answer, I have fixed it because there were some C# statement mixed with VB.NET code. Now it is all for VB.NET

Comment: @Steve Thank you that has fixed a lot of the problems :) However I am still having a few issues. OleDbConnection & OleDbCommand are not defined and I do not know how to fix it. Another issue is that the 'con' part of the first using statement has the issue of 'variable 'con' hides a variable in an enclosing block. I fully appreciate all the help you have given me.

Comment: To fix the first problem you should import the namespace System.Data.OleDb (or prefix the variables with the full name System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection). The second problem should be caused by another variable named con that is visible where you have inserted the code above. Probably that is your previous OleDbConnection declared at the global class level.

Comment: Recheck the answer, another little fix, missing one of the End Using statement

Comment: @Steve Yes you were right I did already have it declared previously which is why is wasn't working. Also could you give more detail into defining the variables, I didn't really understand it.

Comment: Add at the beginning of your file the directive: `Imports System.Data.OleDb`. Now you could declare the variables as explained in the code above without prefixing every statement with the full System.Data.OleDb

Comment: @Steve Ah yes I understand now thank you, however I receive a syntax error with the word imports.

Comment: Don't worry I have found this answer very helpful and will accept it. I just have one last issue in that 'cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()' line produces the 'syntax error in statement' error when attempting to save the data.

Comment: Yeah, I left a comma before the WHERE clause, fixed now

Comment: @Steve Thank you I no longer have any errors, however the code doesn't seem to be saving all of the data to the database.

Comment: Remember to convert the string to numeric when the database field is numeric

Comment: Yes I have done that, here is my new code, if you would like to see it. http://pastebin.com/Kv4JNT6Q

Comment: Wrong. Remember?, in OleDb parameter values  are positionally applied to the placeholders present in your cmdText. In your revised code the first parameter contains the animalName and it is applied to the LatinName field, then everything is moved one field away from where it should go. And you have added a `@p11` without any field to store.

Comment: @steve The 11th field is because when the code didn't work I thought adding it in would make a difference, its a part of the database that doesn't need to be editied. I moved the animalName as it is the first field in the database, when I posted my original code I must have forgotten to change it, I will attempt fix it then let you know if it has worked.

Comment: Here is my new code - http://pastebin.com/G6K95cK2
But I still cannot get the changes to save.

Comment: 11 placeholders (?), 14 parameters

Comment: I had commented them out but then undid it without realising when I copied it on to pastebin, but even with them commented it out it doesnt't work, it was just for personal use. Here is the new code.
http://pastebin.com/UdRkEfrT

Comment: now 11 placeholders and 10 parameters. I am going to bed now. I hope you could find the problem. Goodnight