# Update Access database records by column, row known

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

This is what I've got so far :

```
        Dim myCONN As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=w:\Baza.mdb")

    Dim cmd1 = New OleDbCommand("SELECT ID FROM Baza WHERE NAZIV=@XXNAZIV")
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@XXNAZIV", TextBox2.Text)

    cmd1.Connection = myCONN
    myCONN.Open()
    Dim result = cmd1.ExecuteReader()
    While (result.Read())
        Dim rowx As Integer = GetTextOrEmpty(result("ID"))
    End While
```

I've found the row (rowx) in which I would like to change values in 20 corresponding columns (namesID : NAZIV, SIFRA,...). Data is already presented in textboxes (textbox1...), but I don't know how to finish this code with UPDATE and how to insert changed values back to Access.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim cmdText As String = "UPDATE Baza SET NAZIV=@XXNAZIV Where ID=SomeId"

Using con = new OleDbConnection("PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = h:\Baza.mdb")
Using cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdText, con)
    con.Open()
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@XXNAZIV",TextBox2.Text)

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
End Using
```

This should help you to solve your problem, of course you will have to pass `ID` parameter to query also.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15992314/using-an-update-statement-for-access-database-vb-2008)

Comment: I was using ("SELECT ID FROM Baza WHERE NAZIV=@XXNAZIV") to find row number or ID. I don't want to update NAZIV. 
What I would like is to update all 20 columns corresponding ID (rowx), current values are already set in textboxes (using another code), based on ID number (rowx).

Comment: Thank you for the reference, I get it now.

Comment: You're welcome, I copied and edited the part of code from answer, but I gave the reference just in case.